# Enable / Disable Multiple Google Virtual Keyboard

Tags: javascript

How can use google virtual keyboard to multiple textboxes. I want a checkbox is checked placed above the each textbox to enable virtual keyboard.

I have two textboxes and checkboxes named textbox1,checkbox1,textbox2 and checkbox2. 
I am using this code:

```
var kdp1;
var kdp2;

// This function for checkbox1 for enabling keyboard on textbox1
function checkbox1(chk)
{
    if (chk.checked)
    {
        kdp1 = new google.elements.keyboard.Keyboard(
            [google.elements.keyboard.LayoutCode.MALAYALAM_PHONETIC],
            ['textbox1']);
    }
    else
    {
        kdp1.setVisible(false);
    }
}

// This function for checkbox2 for enabling keyboard on textbox2
function checkbox2(chk)
{
    if (chk.checked)
    {
        kdp2 = new google.elements.keyboard.Keyboard(
            [google.elements.keyboard.LayoutCode.MALAYALAM_PHONETIC],
            ['textbox2']);
    }
    else
    {
        kdp2.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

This enable virtual keyboard on each textbox when checkbox is checked. But problem is when I uncheck the chekbox of one textbox it also hide every virtual keyboard.

I want to hide only one virtual keyboard.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @ArunKillu this enable the virtual keyboard on each textbox. When I uncheck I want to hide only one keyboard but it hide all the virtual keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hide keyboard with its id property changes

```
div#kbd.outerbox {
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```